# In .Net Core 3.1, How can I produce a JsonElement from a Dictionary without having to serialize and deserialize?

Tags: json, asp.net-core-3.1

I am adding some authentication from DocuSign and updating the code to work with .Net Core 3.1.

The original code has:

```
var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

user.Add("access_token", context.AccessToken);
user.Add("refresh_token", context.RefreshToken);
user.Add("expires_in", DateTime.Now.Add(context.ExpiresIn.Value).ToString());

context.RunClaimActions(user);
```

Where user is a JObject from newtonsoft. Updated in .net core 3.1 is RunClaimActions takes a JsonElement.

After looking and trying to use some of the updated objects available, they appear to be immutable. Without knowing everything that could come from the response content, it seems logical to convert it to a dictionary and add the items from the original code. (Note code is not tested yet)

```
var userDocument = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());

var user = userDocument.RootElement.EnumerateObject()
            .ToDictionary(property => property.Name, property => property.Value.GetString());

user.Add("access_token", context.AccessToken);
user.Add("refresh_token", context.RefreshToken);
user.Add("expires_in", DateTime.Now.Add(context.ExpiresIn.Value).ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")));
```

But there seems to be no direct way to produce a JsonElement from this, so the best I can come up with so far is:

```
   context.RunClaimActions(JsonDocument.Parse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(user)).RootElement);
```

Is there something I am completely missing that might make this easier?

The original source code is [on github](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/blob/master/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/Startup.cs#L94).